# WooCommerce Custom Variation Terms Per User

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

Is it possible to change the options in a custom variation dropdown list per user in WooCommerce?

I would like to sell an "upgrade" license product on my website that is visible and is only purchasable by users who had purchased the first version of my software. I have limited the visibility of the "upgrade" product to these users already. For users who had purchased more than one copy, I would like to display a dropdown list for the user to choose which license they would like to buy an upgrade for.

I know how to add variations to a product in WooCommerce, but is it possible to generate the list of options dynamically at runtime?

My best guess was to use the **woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args** hook but that looks wrong after some experimentation. I am hoping there's an elegant way to do this?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, I couldn't find a solution for this via the normal WC route. Instead, I used a plugin called **WC Fields Factory** which allows for use of other input fields other than the normal dropdown box. I used a Hidden type input to pass the necessary information to the product page and used a hook to validate in case of someone trying to do something bad. The plugin allows for the data to be displayed in the cart and checkout pages as well as the order email so it did the trick in a roundabout way.